# Java Play 2.3 F.Promise No Entity Manager bound to this thread

Tags: java, mysql, concurrency, playframework

I'm trying to access mysql database concurrently to get a list of objects using F.Promise , but i get:

> No Entity Manager bound to this thread

although inside the method i call the stored procedure i wrapped it with JPA.withTransactionAsync but still get the same error.

```
 import play.libs.F.*;
 import play.mvc.*;
 import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

 import static play.libs.F.Promise.promise;

 public class Application extends Controller {
 public static Promise<Result> index() {
    return promise(new Function0<Integer>() {
        public Integer apply() {
            return getUserId();
        }
    }).map(new Function<Integer,Result>() {
        public Result apply(Integer i) {
        return ok("Got " + i);
        }
    });
```

and inside getUserId()

```
public static int getUserId()
{
    return JPA.withTransactionAsync(.........);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue - you can see a discussion of it [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/4225).

To quote James Roper...

---

Using transactions across threads introduces deadlocks. Here's the problem:

- Request A acquires a connection
- Request A does some asynchronous operation, and yields its thread
- Request B gets the thread, tries to acquire a connection, but blocks because the connection pool is empty
- Request A's asynchronous operation finishes, and so it goes in the queue to execute, and ultimately return the connection back to the pool, but it can't execute because the thread is being held by Request B, waiting for a connection, which it will never get, because it is waiting for A to return it, which it can't....

So we have a deadlock. The scenario above describes a simplistic scenario where there's only one connection and one thread, but we had many users seeing production deadlocks in more realistic scenarios where many threads were blocked on the connection pool, and many connection holding threads were blocked waiting for the connection pool blocked threads to yield.

The solution is to use an asynchronous connection pool, which unfortunately, JPA doesn't support. A work around is to have a dedicated thread pool that's used to asynchronously acquire connections, that way, when the connection pool is exhausted, the dedicated thread will block, but that doesn't impact anything (except possibly nested attempts to get a connection) because it's only used for acquiring connections from the pool.

---

So, you have 3 options:

1. You can use [this library](https://github.com/schaloner/async-transactions) which handles the closing of the entity manager correctly but is still open to the deadlock issue described above.
2. Use `JPA.withTransaction` instead of `JPA.withTransactionAsync`.
3. Use Ebean, which doesn't have these issues.

EDIT: For completeness, I'm going to add option 4 (my preferred solution) which is to not use an ORM framework and replace it with jOOQ.